# Giving different attributes to different polygons symbols in the same shape layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have several polygons in the same shapefile with the same symbology. I'd like to change the symbology of some polygons in ArcGIS Pro. How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: Select by attribute all the records with Polygone3.  USe the field calculator to calculate the field to your change.  All ArcGIS (and QGIS) operation respect the selection and will only update those selected records.